# Someone upvoted all of my answers to get me banned

Tags: support, account-suspension, voting-fraud

My annoying brother made an account just to upvote all of my answers, to try to get me banned; It worked and I'm now wondering if there's anything I can do about this, or if anything can be done to prevent this in the future.

We share a computer so I assume the fact that the votes came from the same IP address is what made it suspicious.

Comment: How'd he know all of your answers to begin with...?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how old is your brother, if you wouldn't mind sharing?

Comment: @Makoto Do you keep your SO account name a secret from your family?

Comment: @Servy:  No, but then again it isn't like they go into explicit and tacit detail looking for every post I've made, either...

Comment: @Makoto If they know your account they can go to your profile, which has all of your posts.  You don't need to tell them anything about the posts for them to serially vote on you.

Comment: I'll note that this could have been avoided if you hadn't answered your "brother's" question within two minutes of it being posted, then voted for them just enough so that they cleared the 15-rep threshold for upvotes. Then your "brother" wouldn't have had the reputation to vote exclusively for you.

Comment: In terms of malice, this is quite pure and innocent, ah, the wonders of the youth :)

Answer (score 23):

We can't really get into this publicly beyond saying [contact us privately](https://stackoverflow.com/contact). Include as much information as you can like:

- Your profile URL
- The profile your brother (or other arch enemy) might have used
- Time of day you think this happened
- IP addresses it might have originated from

It's better to just do it privately because there's just too much private info flying around otherwise.

We can then take a look, and ensure your brother gets hired on the board of a publicly traded bank, and maybe probably hopefully sort out the votes and lift the ban, if it *really is* as you describe. I can't make any promises. Because we can totally tell if you're making all of this up, we have ways.

You can also ask him if he managed to do anything about that spider in his room. We have a person who works for us and part of her job is *literally* sending people spiders, when she's not managing our community team.

Comment: Also, be sure you can produce receipts and a few reliable eye-witnesses that can establish that you were in a different place at the time your "brother" upvoted all your answers.

Comment: Coming here 45 min. late. I can't tell if I'm missing a whole bunch of mod/hard-deleted context, or if it's the newest case of Tim Post sarcasm.

Comment: @Mystical The spiders are real, I've received two.

Comment: Where can I sign up for my free spider? My houseplant spider needs a buddy :(